# Can't set Silverlight play position when playing back SmoothStreaming asset

Tags: silverlight, streaming, smoothing

We have a pop-up on our Silverlight player that basically asks whether you'd like to go back to the beginning when resuming play.  If yes, we set the position on the ActiveMediaPlugin as follows.

```
 ActiveMediaPlugin.Position = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
```

This works fine for WMV files but does nothing if we're playing back a smoooth streaming asset.  When i step through the code in the SmoothStreamingPlugin, you see the line:

```
  MediaElement.Position = value;
```

being excecuted but it doesn't change the target.

Anyone trod this path?

Mark